# Is it possible to use IntelliJ in a team that everyone use Eclipse and checkin via SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, intellij-idea

We have a small group of developers constantly check in progress via SVN, everyone use Eclipse or STS for every project. I started to use IntelliJ and found it is very powerful, however I am not sure if it is actually practical or a good idea to use it in the group projects as everyone check in not only code but project files as well. I think theoretically it should be fine? But please share any real-time experience?

Comment: Use what your team uses. They may pick tools that are suboptimal, but you'll only make everyone's life more difficult if you try and go this route.

Comment: @David Lively good point, I may get kicked out haha @_@, they love open source

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can integrate SVN with IntelliJ. And there is no issues with the check-in, check-out, and in resolving conflicts as well in case of any one of developer is not in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. I guess it just requires to be more careful.

I worked on projects using intelliJ while others were using Eclipse.

It went all fine, you'll just need to make sure you have the same settings for formatting (i.e, if you wanna use ctrl+alt+L in intelliJ), not to commit any intelliJ generated file, etc. in order to avoid conflicts.